# Is it possible to use SonicWall Global VPN on a Mac without installing third party software?

Tags: windows, macos, networking, vpn, osx-yosemite

I use the SonicWall Gobal VPN Client on Windows to connect to a VPN.

Is it possible to use this VPN on Yosemite without having to install third-party software, just creating a new connection on Settings > Network ?

I tried it but there are a lot of configurations that I don't know how to setup.

In the Windows client I just imported an `.rcf` file and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

SonicWall GVC is not compatible with Mac OS or Linux or any OS other than Windows.

You can use NetExtender to connect to the same SonicWall through SSLVPN

Check the [following link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140826134800/https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw10657) for info for regarding the same.